# Regex catch string between strings

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

I created a small function to catch a string between strings.

```
public static string[] _StringBetween(string sString, string sStart, string sEnd)
        {

            if (sStart == "" && sEnd == "")
            {
                return null;
            }
            string sPattern = sStart + "(.*?)" + sEnd;
            MatchCollection rgx  = Regex.Matches(sString, sPattern);
            if (rgx.Count < 1)
            {
                return null;
            }
            string[] matches = new string[rgx.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < matches.Length; i++)
            {
                matches[i] = rgx[i].ToString();
                //MessageBox.Show(matches[i]);
            }

            return matches;
        }
```

However if i call my function like this: `_StringBetween("[18][20][3][5][500][60]", "[", "]");`
It will fail. A way would be if i changed this line `string sPattern = "\\" + sStart + "(.*?)" + "\\" + sEnd;`
However i can not because i dont know if the character is going to be a bracket or a word.

Sorry if this is a stupid question but i couldn't find something similar searching.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to return, a string array of "[18], [20], [3]..." or a string array of "18, 20, 3..."? That code will return the first, but it's named as if you expect it to return the later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A way would be if i changed this line string `sPattern = "\\" + sStart + "(.*?)" + "\\" + sEnd;` However i can not because i don't know if the character is going to be a bracket or a word.

You can escape all meta-characters by calling [`Regex.Escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string sPattern = Regex.Escape(sStart) + "(.*?)" + Regex.Escape(sEnd);
```

This would cause the content of `sStart` and `sEnd` to be interpreted literally.

Comment: I tried what you previously posted as well and it failed that is why i posted! Thank you :)

Comment: yes of course, it works like a charm. Waiting to accept answer!